# Drawing mathematical stuff with Python

Tags: python

I had asked in my previous question for a package that lets me draw circles and arrows with python and it was suggested that I should try out PyQt4.

My problem is that I have tried to find functions that would let me draw such widgets but have been unable to do so.

So my question is that if anybody knows how to draw circles,arrows and other mathematical symbols in PyQt4 please guide me in the right direction.

btw if anyone of you knows of any package in Python that would let me do so please help.

I need to draw NFA's in my program and thus would need this.

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:NFAexample.svg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aNFAexample.svg)

Thanks a lot

---

As an update I would like to mention that I am not only interested in PyQt4 . If you are aware of any such package that can let me draw mathematical GUI with python please help :)

Comment: If you haven't seen the tutorial http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/, it may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this part of the API: http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qgraphicsitem.html

I believe that class and its subclasses will do what you want.  For some things, like arrows, you may have to construct them out of existing elements such as lines or define your own subclass of qgraphicsitem that does what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Using [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) you can make diagrams like this

[image]

using code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import os
import subprocess
import shlex

# dot code based on http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery/directed/fsm.html
dot='''    
digraph finite_state_machine {
        bgcolor="#ffffff"
        rankdir=LR;
        size="8,5"
        node [shape = doublecircle]; S₁ S₃;
        node [shape = circle]; S₀ S₂ S₄;
        node [shape = circle]; S₄; 
        S₀ -> S₁ [ label = ε, weight=-1 ];
        S₀ -> S₃ [ label = ε, weight=-1 ];
        S₁ -> S₂:nw [ label = 0 ];
        S₂ -> S₁:se [ label = 0 ];
        S₁ -> S₁ [ label = 1 ];
        S₂ -> S₂ [ label = 1 ];
        S₃ -> S₄:nw [ label = 1 ];
        S₄ -> S₃:se [ label = 1 ];
        S₃ -> S₃ [ label = 0 ];
        S₄ -> S₄ [ label = 0 ]; 
}
'''
os.chdir('/tmp')
with open('output_dot.svg','w') as outfile:
    subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('dot -Tsvg'),
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=outfile).communicate(dot)
```

Usually, one calls the graphviz `dot` program from the command-line. It has nothing to do with Python, per se.

To make diagrams programmatically, however, you could use Python to construct the `dot` code as a giant string, and use `subprocess.Popen` to process the string through `dot`. `dot` can output in many formats, including SVG or PNG. Or, you may want to research [pygraphviz](http://networkx.lanl.gov/pygraphviz/) for a more "Pythonic" interface to the graphviz library.

Also note that graphviz supports UTF-8 encoded characters, so you can include subscripts and other math symbols in your diagram by finding the appropriate symbols in the UTF-8 character set.

One of graphviz's strengths is that you don't have to tediously specify the layout of the diagram -- you just say what nodes are connected to what other nodes. The location of the nodes is determined by graphviz (mostly) automatically.

This strength is also somewhat debilitating -- it's hard to place elements in the diagram exactly as you might wish. Notice, for example, that S1 and S2 are not horizontally aligned. I also don't know how to make the arrow from S0 --> S1 more prettily curved, arrows between S1 and S2 perfectly symmetric, or how to make the edge label from S2 --> S1 appear below the arrow, etc...
There might be a way to do all these things, but I don't know how.

For more examples of what graphviz can do, see the [graphviz gallery](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php).

Comment: @user506710: Oh, in that case you are probably better off with PyQt4.

Comment: But like I said I am having real problems due to lack of examples and documentation with PyQt4. Could you help me if you know how to proceed in it??

Comment: nice hack (Unicode subscripts). Regrettably, the characters aren't found by Acrobat in the default font when I render to pdf...

Comment: @Nicolas78: Hm, that is unfortunate. I don't know the answer of hand. Maybe if you post a question showing how you render to pdf, someone will know the solution. (I would like to know too.)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/). Might just suit your needs! Since you are looking to draw NFAs.The [gallery](http://networkx.lanl.gov/gallery.html) shows some of the things that can be done.